# How to count the number of occurences of a warning messages in the current session?

Tags: message-coding

After reading:

[How to count the actual occurence of a warning message in a Do loop?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96221/how-to-count-the-actual-occurence-of-a-warning-message-in-a-do-loop)

I wonder about a broader question: how to count the number of occurences of a warning messages in the current session ?

My first try was

```
counter[arg_] := Module[{}, count++; Return[arg]];
$MessagePrePrint = counter[#] &;
count = 0;

count
Do[1/0, {k, 1, 3}];
count
```

Obviously,

```
count
Quiet[Do[1/0, {k, 1, 3}]];
count
```

doesn't increment the counter.

Now, to keep a tally of all message and hide them, I experimented

```
counterQuiet[arg_] := Module[{}, count++; Return[Null]];
$MessagePrePrint = counterQuiet[#] &;
count = 0;

count
Do[1/0, {k, 1, 3}];
count
```

but it isn't a smart trick, because this way messages are still visible, albeit containing `Null` instead of the original argument.

Can the goal be achieved without redirecting `stderr` to a dummy stream ?

Otherwise, how to implement the redirection and still count messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The down values of the built-in symbol [`MessageList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageList.html) track all the messages emitted in a given kernel session. It can be used to get the count you want by evaluating

```
 count := Total[Length /@ DownValues[MessageList][[All, 2]]];
```

Then each time you evaluate `count`, you will the current total of the messages emitted so far in your kernel session. Here is an image of an example session (starting with a fresh kernel).

[image: session]

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

This solution was completely beyond my capability, owing to my lack of deep understanding of MessageList. It rises to me more doubts about MessageList, and I will post them as detached questions.

P.S. Please, feel always free to remark upon my error in English. I will edit my questions to adjust them.

Answer (score 5):

```
sessionCount = 0;

Check[1/0, sessionCount++; $Failed] & /@ Range[3] // Quiet;

sessionCount

(*  3  *)

Check[1/0, sessionCount++; $Failed] & /@ Range[5] // Quiet;

sessionCount

(*  8  *)
```